# How to invoke the microservice from a Python script

Tags: python, nameko

This code defines the services:

```
from nameko.rpc import rpc


class GreetingService:
    name = "greeting_service"

    @rpc
    def hello(self, name):
        return "Hello, {}!".format(name)
    
class MultiplyService:
    name = "multiply_service"
    
    @rpc
    def multiple(self,a,b):
        return str(int(a) * int(b))
```

I have the services running: [image]

I can open a nameko shell and access the microservice:
[image]
[image]

I want to access the microservice from another Python script. What am I missing?
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

The `n` global is only available inside `nameko shell`.

To invoke an RPC from a script, you need to use the one of the "standalone" clients in `nameko.standalone.rpc`.

Example in the docs here https://nameko.readthedocs.io/en/stable/built_in_extensions.html#rpc